# How to center elements inside an element

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to center 3 divs inside a div.

Here is my code example

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}
.plaatje {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
#plaatje1 {
  background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/c3d5dbc04f664a3386b372d8e4ceb4c7.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#plaatje2 {
  background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/2bcfd124f98a448cbae822337818ff4e.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#plaatje3 {
  background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/e1b7059d626f47cb94535bbba9887cc1.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="plaatje1" class="plaatje">
  </div>

  <div id="plaatje2" class="plaatje">

  </div>
  <div id="plaatje3" class="plaatje">

  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, there is still a white space on the right hand-side of the picture, I have marked it so you know what i'm talking about.

[image]

It also needs to scale, so if I resize the window, that the third image doesn't pops below the first or that the space exists when I resize it fully.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26jmxrb5/) which demonstrates how you can do this using flexbox. It doesn't require floating the elements and gives you with exactly what you're looking for.

I have added a wrapper around the images (.images) and given it the flex properties required to align its contents, then removed the floats and a few other unnecessary things.

Here is the browser support for flexbox: [caniuse:flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
body {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
}
.images {
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.plaatje {
    width: 30%;
    height: 70%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#plaatje1 {
    background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/c3d5dbc04f664a3386b372d8e4ceb4c7.png");
}
#plaatje2 {
    background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/2bcfd124f98a448cbae822337818ff4e.png");
}
#plaatje3 {
    background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/e1b7059d626f47cb94535bbba9887cc1.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="images">
        <div id="plaatje1" class="plaatje"></div>
        <div id="plaatje2" class="plaatje"></div> 
        <div id="plaatje3" class="plaatje"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but now the edges (left of spongebob and right to patrick star) have spaces, how would I get rid of those?

Comment: nevermind, i've got it sorted, do you mind telling me what justify-content does? I removed the line and I see no visual change?

Comment: Henry explained the reason for the gaps either side, we both took your code to mean you wanted that. The justify-content is what keeps them in the centre if they aren't full width. When you have them fill the space, you no longer need this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply try adding `text-align:center;` to your container div

Comment: I'm not trying to align text.

Comment: Do you want the three boxes to be centered inside your container div?

Comment: yes, with no space left and right of the three images.

Comment: Then my answer will answer your initial question of 'How to center elements inside an element'. Right, well then it's obvious, you've got your images set to 30%.. that's not going to fill the space is it? Try Flex box like others have mentioned.

Comment: Or you could look into incorporating Bootstrap into your site?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, and you should probably start with http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp - this elementary level question often gets flagged as not appropriate for SO.

But! Welcome. Here's one way you could do this - I've added comments to explain what's going on. Basically your `float: left` by definition made the `.plaatje`s impossible to center; and the `text-align: center` needs to be on the containing element

```css
body {
  position: fixed; /* probably don't actually want */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0; /* add */
}
#container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  text-align: center; /* add */
}
.plaatje {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* float: left;        // remove
  text-align: center;*/
  display: inline-block; /* add */
}
#plaatje1 {
  background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/c3d5dbc04f664a3386b372d8e4ceb4c7.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#plaatje2 {
  background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/2bcfd124f98a448cbae822337818ff4e.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#plaatje3 {
  background-image: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/e1b7059d626f47cb94535bbba9887cc1.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="plaatje1" class="plaatje">
  </div><div id="plaatje2" class="plaatje">

  </div><div id="plaatje3" class="plaatje">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- removed spaces between the divs -->
```

Comment: The problem with inline block is that it will create spaces between the elements which are a pain to get rid of. Also w3 schools is a terrible resource and I would highly recommend MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: That's why I removed the spaces between the `.plaatje`. MDN as you know mostly doesn't include tutorials, and in this case I don't see an overview on MDN of how to center things. w3schools was pretty rough years ago but is now a solid resource for beginners.

Comment: Fair comment on the tutorials. The workaround for inline-block is hideous in my opinion, it relies on a quirk of html which is in no way clear to the reader while there are much more appropriate means of achieving the same thing available. However it does do the job.

Comment: It's not really a quirk or inappropriate - whitespace between inline blocks is preserved, so to have no rendered space between them don't put any whitespace between them in the markup. That said, it is a little tricky and I definitely agree that flexbox is a good tool for this. My answer is how to make the OP's code work the way he expected it to, yours is "you might be happier trying this route instead"… probably both will be helpful

Comment: Yeah, but now the edges (left of spongebob and right to patrick star) have spaces, how would I get rid of those?

Comment: Well you have three elements each 30% wide, so there's going to be 5% space on the left and right edges…